# How to reset a thread pool efficiently

Tags: java, concurrency, threadpool

I'm using a thread pool to enable multiple unimportant tasks to be queued and (potentially) executed however I need to be able to easily cancel all queued and executing tasks and start a new queue from scratch.

ie:

```
// startup
pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

// reset
pool.shutdownNow();
pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

The implementation I'm using now seems to work but I'm not sure that shutting down completely and creating a new thread pool is particularly efficient.

The reset happens regularly, in some usages it happens just as regularly as scheduling a task! Since there is no way to determine if any tasks are awaiting execution (or is there?) I feel I am shutting down the pool way too often.

Is there a more suitable pool implementation or a better way to achieve this functionality?

**EDIT: solution**

I'm now running with:

```
// startup
pool = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

// reset
for (Future<?> task : pool.getQueue().toArray(new Future[0]))
    task.cancel(true);
```

I've ignored the call to 'purge' because this is slow and the queue will be tidied up later by the pool anyway. I am aware that currently executing tasks may not be terminated by this and that works for me.

thanks.

Comment: If you have answered your question, put the answer ***in the answer section***, not the question.

Comment: @NicolBolas thanks for the downvote and reprimand. I used one of the posters answers which was quite helpful, but wanted to clarify my usage of it in case that helps people in future. I didn't want to claim all the glory for myself by self-answering with something that I copied from someone else. Some of you people are way too precious which really detracts from using the most helpful resource on the web. Why not turn your attention to posts that really need help instead of weighing in on already solved and otherwise good questions. have a nice day.

Comment: "*I didn't want to claim all the glory for myself by self-answering with something that I copied from someone else.*" Then post your answer and upvote/accept *theirs*. It's not about "claiming glory"; it's about proper organization. Questions go in the top, answers in the "Answers" section. That's what makes this a "helpful resource". Answering your own question is fine. "*Why not turn your attention to posts that really need help instead of weighing in on already solved and otherwise good questions.*" It stopped being a "good question" when you put an *answer* in it. Hence the downvote.

Comment: different strokes for different folks.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can cancel all pending (and, probably running) tasks:

```
for (Future f: pool.getQueue().toArray(new Future[0]))
{
    f.cancel(true); // or false
}
pool.purge();
```

Comment: The `Future` is an internal wrapper inside of the `ExecutorService`.  You never implement `Future` yourself.  Doing that 'cancel(...)` is _not_ going to interrupt the associated thread.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work that way either @Valeri.  Those will still be considered just `Runnable`.  The `FutureTask` is created by the concurrent classes only.

Comment: @Gray I don't see why you can't create `FutureTask`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html

Comment: You can create it @Valeri but when you submit it to the thread-pool, it's going to wrap your task in another one.  That's the way it works.  You don't submit a `Future` or a `FutureTask`.  You submit a `Runnable` or a `Callable`.  Take a look at the `submit(...)` method code in a debugger.

Comment: @Gray, you are right, I've just checked from sources. But that makes the task simpler: no need to subclass... Just cancel all futures from the queue.

Comment: just need to state that pool can be cast to ThreadPoolExecutor for this functionality

Comment: Why do u need to have a loop and cancel all manually. Calling shutdownnow cancels the running tasks and do not execute the remaining tasks that were lined up. I dont see any point in doing it

Comment: @Jatin `shutdownNo` stops the executor

Comment: @ValeriAtamaniouk purge is slow and will effectively happen anyway over time.

Answer (score 0):

You could monitor all of the `Future`s you get from submitting the tasks and `cancel()` all of them which would allow you to re-use the thread-pool without recreated.  However, I doubt that you would gain too much extra efficiency.

As long as you aren't doing this too often, I think your mechanism should work fine.  One thing to realize is that although you are calling `pool.shutdownNow()`, this will only interrupt the running jobs which won't necessarily stop them.  It depends on what they are doing and whether they are executing methods that throw `InterruptedException` often or listening to the thread interrupt flag.  So even if `shutdownNow()` returns, some of the tasks may still be executing.

Comment: yes i understand that shutdown and cancel does not necessarily stop running task/threads. surely though, cancelling tasks before they execute would be more efficient than terminating and recreating everything including threads, queues etc.?

Comment: More efficient but I'd say only slightly.  It depends on how often you are doing it.  I means that you need to add code to manage the lists of running tasks which is overhead as well.  I suspect when you time the new way you won't see a significant difference.  The answer you chose was completely wrong 2 times until I corrected it and I proposed that mechanism from the start.  But oh well @pstanton.

Comment: +1 and appreciate the answer, ThreadPoolExecutor.getQueue means i don't have to manage a list. thanks for the help. not sure why anyone downvoted your answer either, i hate it when people do that without commenting...